# Reference a function using call

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to reference a Javascript built-in function, but I can't manage to make a reference to `call` function and use it under another name.

Requirements are:

- In unit tests, the function will be called like `foo('string')`.
- It would be best not to create a new function, but make a function reference that works.

```js
const s = 'ABCDEFG';
console.log(''.toLowerCase.call(s)); // Correctly outputs 'abcdefg'
const foo = ''.toLowerCase.call;
console.log(foo); // Correctly outputs 'function call() { [native code] }'
foo(s); // Throws 'foo is not a function'
```

To compare, if I use my own function, the function reference works.

```js
function call (x) {
  return x.toLowerCase();
}

const s = 'ABCDEFG';
console.log(call(s)); // Outputs 'abcdefg'
foo = call;
console.log(foo); // Outputs 'function...'
foo(s); // 'abcdefg'
```

Maybe functional features of Javascript such as partials or currying would help, but I can't understand how to make it work.

Comment: you can have something like `foo = ''.toLowerCase; foo.call(s);`

Comment: The error message in FF might make clear what happens: "_Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
foo = String.prototype.toLowerCase.call.bind(String.prototype.toLowerCase)
foo(s)
```

or this:

```
foo = String.prototype.toLowerCase.call;
foo.call(String.prototype.toLowerCase, s)
```

It seems very counter intuitive but in fact all `call` functions on all native functions are exactly the same. The JS engine doesn't create separate functions (as it usually does for non-native invocations). This means that in order to invoke the `call`, you need provide its `this` as first argument as I am doing in the examples above - either by calling `foo.call(ActualFunction)` or by binding. Here's a short snippet that shows that all `call` functions are actually the same:

```js
let x = String.prototype.toLowerCase.call;
let y = String.prototype.toUpperCase.call;
let z = String.prototype.indexOf.call;
console.log(Object.is(x, y));
console.log(Object.is(x, z));
// Even across different prototypes!
let w = parseInt.call;
console.log(Object.is(x, w));
```

Comment: Great information, I used the shortest version: `const foo = Object.call.bind(''.toLowerCase);`

Comment: This will create a new function, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foo` as a function:

```
const foo = function(data){ 
    return ''.toLowerCase.call(data)
};
```

Now call `foo(s)`, it gives the expected result:

```js
const foo = function(data) {
  return ''.toLowerCase.call(data)
};

const s = 'ABCDEFG';
console.log(foo(s))
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a reference to an already existing function, not to create a new function.